# Calculating $1-\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}-\frac{1}{4^4} \ldots$ using Fourier series

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am working on the following exercise:

> Find the Fourier series of the function $f(x) = (x^2-\pi^2)^2$ and $-\pi 
>  < x < \pi$. Use it to calculate the sum of $1-\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}-\frac{1}{4^4} \ldots$

The Fourier series is defined as: $$ \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n cos(nt) + b_nsin(nt) \ dt$$

Where $$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) cos(nt) \ dt $$
for $n = 0,1,2, \ldots$  .

And $$b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) sin(nt) \ dt $$
for $n = 1,2,3 \ldots$  .

Using the computer I found that $a_0 = \dfrac{16{\pi}^4}{15}$ and for $n>0$:
$$a_n = -\dfrac{\left(16{\pi}^2n^2-48\right)\sin\left({\pi}n\right)+48{\pi}n\cos\left({\pi}n\right)}{\pi n^5}
= \pm \frac{48}{n^4}$$
and 
$$b_n = 0.$$

But how can we use this to calculate $1-\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}-\frac{1}{4^4} \ldots$ ?

EDIT: If someone else should ever need this, here is the answer: In total we have that 
$$(t^2-\pi^2)^2 = \dfrac{8{\pi}^4}{15} + 48 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^4} cos(nt)$$

We set $t= 0$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sin(n\pi)=0$ and $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$. Can you go on from this?

Comment: No sorry that does not get me much further. Using this I see that the Fourier Series is $24 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{48}{n^4} cos(nt)$. But what comes after that?

Comment: No, the series is $24+48\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cos(nt)}{n^4}$. You set $t=0$ and you are done.

Comment: It is also $a_0=\frac{8}{15}\pi^4$. This should be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help.